# Finding average value of list elements, if a condition is met using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math

I have a list that has the following format:

```
mylist = ["Joe, 100%", "Joe, 80%", "Joe, 90%", "Sally, 95%", "Sally, 80%", "Jimmy, 90%", ...]
```

What I am trying to do is, first count the number of times each name appears. If a name appears 2 or more times, append that name along with the average percent. So, I'm trying to get to the following output:

```
newlist = ["Joe, 90%", "Sally, 87.5%"]
```

To try this, I did `mylist.split(", ")` to get the names only, and used `Counter()` to find how many times the name appears. Then, I used a simple `if >= 2` statement to append the name to `newlist` if the name appears 2 or more times.

However, despite trying many different things, but I wasn't able to figure out how to get the percentages back with the name in the final list. I also am unsure how to word my question on Google, so I wasn't able to find any help. Does anyone know how to do this? If this question is a duplicate, please let me know (and provide a link so I can learn), and I can delete this question. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your code? Specifically a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @kopecs Hi. There really isn't much to show because I've just modified and tried different things I found online and none worked for my situation, so I got rid the code as I tried different things. I'm not really sure where to begin to try to create my own solution because I'm relatively new to programming. Thats why I added the last 2 paragraphs, to at least show that I've tried.

Comment: abhilb gives an answer that is pretty much exactly what I would suggest then. You might also want to look at the documentation for [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) if you haven't seen it used before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
percents = defaultdict(int)

for item in mylist:
    name, percent = item.split(',')
    percent = int(percent.lstrip().rstrip('%'))
    percents[name]+=percent
    counts[name]+=1

result = []
for k,v in counts.items():
    if v > 1:
        result.append(f"{k}, {percents[k]/v}%")
print(result)
```

**Output**

`['Joe, 90.0%', 'Sally, 87.5%']`

Comment: As an additionally note, this works as calling `int()` with no arguments returns 0.

Comment: Great answer, although for this situation I'd want to do `float()` to allow float percents. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you create a dictionary of the scores, where the key would be the name and the value would be a list of their scores. This snippet shows how you can achieve that:

```
mydict = {}
for item in mylist:
    name, score = item.split(", ") # splits each item into a score and a name
    score = float(score.replace("%", "")) # converts string score to a float
    if mydict[name]: # checks if the name already exists in the dictionary
        mydict[name].append(score)
    else:
        mydict[name] = [score]
```

This would would leave you with a dictionary of scores that is organized by their name. Now all you would have to do is average the scores in the dictionary:

```
newlist = []
for name in mydict:
    if len(mydict[name]) >= 2:
        average = str(sum(mydict[name]))/len(mydict[name])) + "%"
        straverage = name + ", " + average
        newlist.append(straverage)
```

Comment: No, the first part of the code will account for all the values in the original list, appending all values to the dictionary. In the second part of the code, it will average them and then format it into the newlist as specified by OP

Comment: My bad, i just fixed the code. Thanks for the catch.